# Display error messages in multiple locations using zod

Tags: react-hook-form, zod

I have a form created with zod.
Both are optional inputs, but I want to make sure that both are input if one is input.
And I want to display the error message on both sides.

So I wrote the code as below.

```
const schema = z.object({
  samplea: z.string().optional(),
  sampleb: z.string().optional(),
}).refine(
  (args) => {
    if (args.samplea || args.sampleb) {
      return args.samplea && args.sampleb ? true : false;
    }
    return true;
  },
  {
    message: "If you enter, please enter both",
    path: ["samplea", "sampleb"],
  }
);

...

<Box>
  <FormLabel>samplea</FormLabel>
  <TextField
    type="text"
    {...register("samplea")}
    error={!!errors.samplea}
    helperText={errors.samplea?.message}
  />
</Box>

<Box>
  <FormLabel>sampleb</FormLabel>
  <TextField
    type="text"
    {...register("sampleb")}
    error={!!errors.sampleb}
    helperText={errors.sampleb?.message}
  />
</Box>
```

There is a problem that the error message can only be displayed for "sampleb".
I would like to know how to make both "samplea" and "sampleb" error and display error messages for both.

Comment: Perhaps 'samplea' does not have an error message because its not erroring out. Have you tried checking the internals of the zod error object.

Answer (score 4):

To solve this use [`superRefine`](https://zod.dev/?id=superrefine). It can be used for creating multiple issues and customizing error codes.

```
const schema = z
  .object({
    samplea: z.string().optional(),
    sampleb: z.string().optional(),
  })
  .superRefine((args, ctx) => {
    if (!args.samplea && !args.sampleb) {
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
        path: ["samplea"],
        fatal: true,
        message: "If you enter, please enter both",
      });
      ctx.addIssue({
        code: z.ZodIssueCode.custom,
        path: ["sampleb"],
        fatal: true,
        message: "If you enter, please enter both",
      });
    }
});
```

In the above code block, `superRefine` has two params `args` (can be named anything), which represents the values of the object and we also have `ctx` which contains methods from `superRefine`.

Next, using an `if` statement, we determine if both fields contain any value. In the event that the condition `!args.samplea && !args.sampleb` evaluates to is true, `ctx.addIssue` is triggered. This allows us to define the following:

- `code`: Enables you to customize your issue.
- `path`: The desired field.
- `fatal`: Used to abort early, preventing other refinements from executing.
- `message`: Enter a validation message.